# R: How can I source an entire project from GitHub?

Tags: r, github

I've got a GitHub project with interdependent R scripts, some of which I want to source. When I run

```
source_https <- function(url) {
    require(RCurl)
    sapply(c(url), function(u) {
        eval(parse(text = getURL(u, followlocation = TRUE, cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))), envir = .GlobalEnv)
    })
}

source_https("https://path_to_repository/one_of_the_scripts.R")
```

I, naturally, get an error message:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'another_script.R': No such file or directory
```

Is there any way I could source the entire project?

Comment: "GitHub project with interdependent R scripts" Why is that not a package?

Comment: It started as a standalone tool, and then I saw that some functions might be useful in other projects. I'd like to give other users a convenient way to import functions without having to clone the GitHub project.

Comment: If you want to provide this for others, create a package (including documentation and tests). Installation is then simple with `devtools::install_github`.

Comment: Had to invest some time into learning how to create an R package, but should be time well spent!

Comment: Exactly. A package gives you a nice standardized infrastructure and you do not have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it into an R package, as [roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland) suggested, solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be the following one:

```
source_https <- function(url) {
    require(RCurl)
    sapply(c(url), function(u) {
        getURL(u, followlocation = TRUE, cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
    })
}

source_https("https://path_to_repository/one_of_the_scripts.R")
```

I don't see qhy using eval(parse(...))

Comment: This only outputs the contents of the file. Anyway, I have no trouble sourcing a single file as long as it doesn't depend on other files. What I'm looking for is a way to source an entire project.